# Failure to render changes in RoR Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started Lesson 5 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl: Filling in the Layout Adding Some Structure

My changes though are have not been rendering since late Lesson 3. When I make a change in any of the Pages (home.html.erb, about.html.erb, etc) I have no problems. But things like Sign In and the title do not change.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <%= yield %>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/contact"
  get "pages/about"
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>This is the home page for the <a href="http://railstutorial.org">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> sample application.</p>
```

Again, my page just render a what it did in Chapter three with no stylesheets, no changes to the nav bar, and the incorrect title (localhost:3000/pages/home) instead of Ruby on Rails Sample App.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes navbar, navbar-fixed-top which you are using are not there is css, those are part of twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 which is a collection of css classes and javascript functions. So for this code to work, first include bootstrap.css file in the Railsproject/app/assets/stylesheets/ directory. You can download the bootstrap compiled files here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ 
Note: the bootstrap.css is situated in bootstrap-2.3.2/dist/css/ directory. Just copy that file and everything will work fine.

you made a mistake in your application.html.erb syntax.

don't use  tag for defining classes of nav, use  tag instead.
so the correct syntax is :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I think that should fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either. Do you know why that is?

Comment: collapse the navbar, are you using twitter bootstrap 3?, go to : getbootstrap.com  checkout the components section in that site. you will find lot of templates and code for that stuff. Better to use that and change, rather than write everything physically